# Const after operator function c++

Tags: c++

I'm learning `C++` i saw a `const` after an operator function.
It doesn't make sense because the function returns the same value regardless of the `const`.
What's the purpose of using it?

```cpp
using namespace std;

class Person {
public:
    int age;
    Person(int age) : age(age) {}

    int operator *(int &b) const {
        return b;
    }
};

int main() {
    Person *p = new Person(11);

    int a = 19;

    cout << *p * a; // prints 19

    delete p;
}
```

Comment: [OT]:- >`Person p(11);` (and `std::cout << p * a;`). So you avoid memleak.

Comment: The linked explanation is a bit wordy, tl;dr: it tells the compiler "this is safe to call on `const Person` objects".

Comment: @Jarod42 Fixed it.

Comment: There is an implicit `this` pointer on member functions.  It's *as if* the member function was `int operator*(Person* this, int& b);` free-standing function.  And with the trailing `const`, *as if* the function was `int operator*(Person const* this, int& b);` free-standing function.  Because the `this` is implicit, when `const` was added to the language around 1989, Bjarne had to figure out how to qualify const from non-const member functions with a backwards compatible syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `const` operator behind a member function applies to the `this` pointer, i.e. it guarantees that the object you call this function on may not be changed by it. It's called a [const-qualified member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-_and_volatile-qualified_member_functions)

If you tried, in this example, to change the persons age in the `operator*()`, you would get a compile error.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. 